How to setup a private network to avoid UDP drops
Related to this question and specifically the second answer, I have a followup question inspired by one comment there. It mentions that ”One is to design the network in such a way that you never have lost or reordered packets”. I would like to see some examples of a private LAN network (no Internet, no routing) where N hosts are streaming each one live video and audio to M hosts on demand using IP multicast. Those hosts are not all connected to the same switches, rather there are two layers, one access and one aggregation layer before reaching the destination host. One host can be subscribed to receive multiple videos at the same time. How can one guarantee no lost or reordered packets?
Note: i do not have enough reputation to reply to his comment and ask there directly.

That can be impossible or quite costly to do what you ask, which is why real-time protocols are designed to accept some loss. You use VoIP and watch videos over the public Internet, and there is often quite a bit of loss that you never know about, plus one-way traffic can be buffered to a certain extent before it starts playing, which allows the real-time protocol to get lost data. There are recommendations, such as Cisco's 20:1 access to distribution and 4:1 distribution to core bandwidth recommendations that are reasonable and cost effective for most businesses.

Very simple: there needs to be sufficient available bandwidth in the network.
If an access switch's uplink supports the total, worst-case bandwidth of all workloads across it, then there's no packet loss. Plan 5-10% extra to make up for jitter and bursts and you're on the safe side.
In practice, Ethernet's 10x speed steps make it rather easy to select the required speed class. Gigabit Ethernet is quite capable of supporting a number of simultaneous streams, and there's little reason to use slower. If 1G doesn't cut it use 10G, especially between access and aggregation, or for aggregation to core. If 10G becomes to slow, go for 25G, 40G or 50G depending on what your favorite vendor is offering.

While it is difficult to achieve 100% loss/reordered free network there are things to consider that help to get close to that goal:

Reliable and good quality (even insulated) cabling
Reliable network hardware
Sufficient in/out buffers on interfaces
Proper QOS setup prioritizing important traffic and not allowing it to be dropped if buffers are full
Proper and stable Spanning Tree config. Even better physically or virtually stack units to simplify design and lessen or completely remove reliance on STP


MoggerRus, how to completely remove reliance on STP in a two layers configuration?

In a controlled datacenter environment you can achieve that since you 1)virtually stack switches and use MCLAG to avoid having active/passive links 2) Knowing what is connected to the ports and shut down unused ports. 3) Use overlay technologies like VXLAN
